How to resolve CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'
I'm trying to set up an venv in Jupyter (Anaconda). The steps I am using are below. I've searched on the error above and tried several things, from initializing the vent to activating Conda; no dice. Any tips? Using a macOS Sonoma. The code and results are below, where the Conda init error message is being generated.
CODE:
!conda create --name test_env --y
!conda init zsh
!source ~/.zshrc
!conda activate test_env

results

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.
